# sql to calculate the daily avg when only change records are available in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of inventory quantity by part#, location# and date.  There is only a record in the table if a change occurred on that day.  For example:

```
part  |loc   |date      |qtyonhand
------+------+----------+---------
10544 | 3012 | 20161116 | 68
10544 | 3012 | 20170403 | 43  <----- 
10544 | 3012 | 20170413 | 33  <-----
```

For each part/loc key, I need to calculate the average quantity on hand over the 
past 3 months.  Since it is May 2017, I need to calculate for Feb, Mar & Apr 2017 which includes the two records shown.  But I can't just take the average of 43 and 33 divided by 2.  For this part/loc the calc should be like this:

```
20170201 inventory was 68
20170202 inventory was 68
...for each day
20170402 inventory was 68
20170403 inventory was 43
20170404 inventory was 43
...
20170413 inventory was 33
...
20170430 inventory was 33
```

and I sum each days inventory and divide by the number of days between Feb 1 and Apr 30.

I tried using lag() to calculate the difference between the dates, and then multiply it by the inventory level, but I can't figure out how to get the values from Feb 1, using the previous change record qty, through the next change record.

Any hints or direction are much appreciated.

Comment: I think that your method to create a table of inventory by day and then aggregate averages from that is reasonable.

Comment: You should edit your question and show the query you are working.

Comment: Degan, any hint as to how to create a table by day that includes the previous change qty if thefor new entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `lag()` and logic on the periods.  If I have the arithmetic right:

```
select part, loc, 
       sum(days_in_period * prev_quantity)/ sum(days_in_period) as average
from (select t.*,
             greatest(least(date, period_end) - greatest(prev_date, period_start) + 1, 0) as days_in_period
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(date) over (partition by part, loc order by date) as prev_date,
                   lag(qtyonhand) over (partition by part, loc order by date) as prev_qtyonhand
            from t
           ) t cross join
           (select '2017-02-01'::date as period_start, '2017-04-30'::date as period_end,
     ) t
group by part, loc;
```